# TFS 2017 On Premise - Access Levels vs Licensing - to use Test features via Web-Access

Tags: tfs

In TFS 2017 On Premise, to gain possibility to utilize features under Test menu of TFS Web Access, one seems to need to have "VS Enterprise Access Level", which is a top level expensive licensing for a tester just for this purpose, as an alternative to do them via MTM.

Also it seems like "Advanced Access Level" is deprecated, hence not a possibility to resolve for the testers.

Didn't find on the internet any relevant info on resolving this issue. Can u pls advise ? Maybe need to open user voice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in TFS no other single/precise permission settings for test feature. We can only manage the users with the [Access levels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/security/access-levels?view=vsts#access-to-the-test-hub-and-marketplace-extensions) for now.

However the requirement make sense, I have submitted a [**user voice here**](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/34073449-add-a-single-permission-settings-that-restrict-the) for you to suggest the feature, you can go and vote it up to achieve that in future.

> The **Advanced** access level is deprecated for TFS 2017 and later
>   versions of TFS. Use the **VS Enterprise** access level only for active
>   Visual Studio Enterprise subscribers. For MSDN Platforms and Visual
>   Studio Test Professional with MSDN subscribers needing access to the
>   Test hub, assign them to the **Advanced** access level and the Test
>   Manager extension.
>
> Full access to the Test hub requires Advanced (TFS 2015) or VS
>   Enterprise (TFS 2017) access. Visual Studio Test Professional plus the
>   Test hub features in the TFS web portal are managed through VSTS,
>   Azure billing services, and purchase of Test Manager extensions from
>   the Marketplace.

Comment: [Thank u kindly]